# Query with Sum( Case When )

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, case

I have a problem in using Sum( Case When ). When I use the below query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [datetime], 111) as [Date],
       Installation_Id,
       Installation_Name,
              Round (ISNULL (sum (case when ((cast([datetime] as time) >= '07:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '09:00:00') or (cast([datetime] as time) >= '16:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '20:00:00') and (Installation_ID = '18374' or Installation_ID = '18466' or Installation_ID = '18375' or Installation_ID = '18372' )) then availability/240 
                                when ((cast([datetime] as time) >= '07:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '09:00:00') or (cast([datetime] as time) >= '16:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '20:00:00') and (Installation_ID = '18373')) then availability/216 
                                when ((cast([datetime] as time) >= '07:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '09:00:00') or (cast([datetime] as time) >= '16:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '20:00:00') and (Installation_ID = '18467' )) then availability/48 end),0),4) as [Availability from 7am to 9am or 4pm to 8pm]
from Reserve_Power
where Installation_Id = 18467
Group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [datetime], 111),Installation_Id,Installation_Name
```

The result that I get is :

**Availabilty = 0.7736**

But when I run the below query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [datetime], 111) as [Date],
       Installation_Id,
       Installation_Name,
       sum (case when ((cast([datetime] as time) >= '07:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '09:00:00') or (cast([datetime] as time) >= '16:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '20:00:00') and (Installation_ID = '18467' )) then availability/48 end) as [Availability from 7am to 9am or 4pm to 8pm]

from Reserve_Power
where Installation_Id = 18467 and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [datetime], 111) = '2023-01-22'
Group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [datetime], 111),Installation_Id,Installation_Name;
```

The result that I get is:

**Availability = 1**

The result from second query is correct, so I assume there is a problem in the part related to Sum() function.

Can you help me with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I did but didn't make any difference!!

Comment: Please build a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) with sample data and desired results. Nobody is going to be able to reverse engineer {big honking query} and figure out what data it came from and why it should produce the result you expect.

Comment: It's a simple dataset. There is an 'availability' column filled with number 4, 12*4 = 48, so divided by 48, should be 1. But when I use it in a Case() - First Query- , I don't understand why it changes to 0.77. I need a help about using Sum with multiple conditions! @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I just explain it maybe someone has something similar in future. The problem was in OR clause and there were missing parentheses. When I used parentheses for OR clause, it was solved.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, [datetime]) as [Date],
       Installation_Id,
       Installation_Name,
              Round (ISNULL (sum (case when (cast([datetime] as time) >= '06:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '22:00:00' and (Installation_ID = '18374' or Installation_ID = '18466' or Installation_ID = '18375' or Installation_ID = '18372' )) then availability/640 
                                when (cast([datetime] as time) >= '06:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '22:00:00' and (Installation_ID = '18373')) then availability/576 
                                when (cast([datetime] as time) >= '06:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '22:00:00' and (Installation_ID = '18467')) then availability/128 end),0),4) as [Availability in critical hours 6am to 10pm],
       Round (ISNULL (sum (case when (((cast([datetime] as time) >= '07:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '09:00:00') or (cast([datetime] as time) >= '16:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '20:00:00')) and (Installation_ID = '18374' or Installation_ID = '18466' or Installation_ID = '18375' or Installation_ID = '18372' )) then availability/240 
                                when (((cast([datetime] as time) >= '07:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '09:00:00') or (cast([datetime] as time) >= '16:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '20:00:00')) and (Installation_ID = '18373')) then availability/216 
                                when (((cast([datetime] as time) >= '07:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '09:00:00') or (cast([datetime] as time) >= '16:00:00' and cast([datetime] as time) < '20:00:00')) and (Installation_ID = '18467' )) then availability/48 end),0),4) as [Availability in critical hours 7am to 9am or 4pm to 8pm]
from Reserve_Power
where Installation_Id = 18373
Group by CONVERT(date, [datetime]),Installation_Id,Installation_Name
```